# PyTorch tensor declared as torch.long becomes torch.int64

Tags: pytorch, tensor, dtype

I am new to PyTorch so I haven't worked a lot with PyTorch Tensors. Something I am puzzled about is if I declare the dytpe of a tensor as `torch.long`, and then check the dtype it is `int64`. For example:

```
In [62]: a = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2],
                       [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
         a.dtype

Out[62]: torch.int64
```

I am probably making some silly mistake.

Why is this happening?

Edit:

```
     89         if isinstance(edge_index, Tensor):
---> 90             assert edge_index.dtype == torch.long
     91             assert edge_index.dim() == 2
     92             assert edge_index.size(0) == 2
```

In my case `a` is `edge_index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch-tensor) we can see that `torch.long` and `torch.int64` are synonymous and both refer to the 64-bit signed integer type.

Comment: Ah I see, problem is that I need it to output `torch.long`, because I am using software which requires that to be the output.

Comment: That seems like some extremely brittle software you're using, I can't imagine such software was written to be compatible with pytorch. Note that `torch.long` is never printed since `torch.long` simply refers to same underlying object as `torch.int64`. I.e. `torch.long is torch.int64` is true, and if you run `print(torch.long)` then `"torch.int64"` will be printed.

Comment: The software I am using is PyTorch Geometric. I have added where the error comes up in my initial post above.

Comment: `edge_index.dtype == torch.long` should evaluate to true if `edge_index` has dtype `torch.int64` since `torch.int64 == torch.long` is true. My guess is your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: You can test this with your initial code `print(a.dtype == torch.long)` should print `True`.

Comment: Yes it does print true, but so do the others. I guess the problem must be somewhere else, but this is where the error is raised. Thanks for all the feedback though, I'll check my code again.

Comment: I'm guessing that `edge_type` has not been converted to a `long` tensor at that point. Possibly related, but keep in mind that `Tensor.to(dtype=torch.long)` and `Tensor.long()` are **not** in-place operations, so you need to assign the value returned from them. For example you need to do `x = x.long()`, just putting `x.long()` by itself won't accomplish anything.

Comment: I will check that as well. Thanks for the help!